# how to access the elements of a dlib matrix / vector?

Tags: c++, dlib

```
std::vector<matrix<float,0,1>> face_descriptors = net(faces);
```

Above is what i was looking for.When I use the following command

```
std:: cout >> face_descriptors[0] >> endl;
```

It outputs the whole matrix.But I want to calculate the distance between two such vectors so how do I access each element individually??
I am using this for real time face recognition.

Comment: The elements of the vector, **are matrices**. It prints the whole matrix because the type of `face_descriptors[0]` is `matrix<float,0,1>`.

Comment: Thanks.But my problem is how do i access each element of those matrices.i need to  access each element one by one in a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example file that illustrates how to use matrix object in dlib http://dlib.net/matrix_ex.cpp.html

You can simply access element of dlib matrix by the () operator

```
matrix<float, 1, 3> mat;
mat = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3;
cout << mat(0) << endl;

matrix<float, 3, 3> mat2;
mat2 = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,
       1.1, 1.2, 1.3,
       2.1, 2.2, 2.3;
cout << mat2(1, 1) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need to calculate the distance between two face descriptors, which are dlib matrices  and packed into std vector.
 To access each matrix element, follow **idurdyev** reply.
 But to calculate euclidean distance between *i* and *j* descriptors simply use dlib function:

```
double distance= length(face_descriptors[i] - face_descriptors[j]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(uint32_t u=0; u<face_descriptors.size(); u++)
{
    cout << face_descriptors[u].nc() << endl;
    cout << face_descriptors[u].nr() << endl;

    for(uint32_t r=0; r<face_descriptors[u].nr(); r++)
        cout << face_descriptors[u](r,0) << endl;
}
```